# Cancel notification started from service

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications

I am writing an application in which i need to display notification from service. I use flag Foreground_service to start notification. Now i want to cancel this notification(from activity) without stopping the service. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a NotificationManager object to cancel a notification, use the same id (that you used to give the notification) and pass that to NoticationManager.cancel(Int):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(1);  // here 1 is the id of that notification
```

further you can see from below about notification manager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29

Comment: this approach does not work when notification set from service. This is used in other cases.